# Iron Router controller inheritance, accessing a ApplicationController outside of file

Tags: meteor

I want to implement an inheritance scheme for my routes. I want all my routes to inherit from my ApplicationController

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.user = Meteor.subscribe('userEarnings', Meteor.userId());
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentUser: Users.findOne(),
      userReady: this.user.ready()
    };
  }
});
```

Which makes sure all custom fields are subscribed to on my user collection. I have the above stored in a file `client/lib/routes/main.js`. I want to be able to extend my other controllers in `client/lib/routes/*.js` with `ApplicationController`, like this

```
historyController = ApplicationController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.subs = Meteor.subscribe("userPurchaseHistory", Meteor.userId());
  },
  data: function() {
    console.log(this.user.ready());
    return {
      purchases: Purchases.find(),
      ready: this.subs.ready()
    };
  }
});

Router.route('history', {
  path: '/history',
  loginRequired: 'entrySignIn',
  controller: historyController
});
```

but currently, I get

`Uncaught ReferenceError: ApplicationController is not defined`

How can I access `ApplicationController` outside of its file? I thought that by not using `var`, the variables would be globally accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a load order issue.  As per [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> File Load Order
>
> All files that match main.* are moved after everything else, preserving their order.
>
> ...
>
> Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by filename.

Try putting the ApplicationController definition in `client/lib/routes/application-controller/application-controller.js` or something like that to make absolutely sure it runs before any of the other controllers try to inherit from it. Provided it's not called `main.js`, having it in a subdirectory will ensure it's added before the stuff in the parent directory and obviate the potential alphabetical order problem.